# Toggle cell value based on previous cell's value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, lookup

I'm looking to make an automated checkin spreadsheet. When the spreadsheet adds a new row, it'll check the value of the last time the name was mentioned, and toggle between the "in" and "out" value.

I've tried to figure it out, but I cannot figure out how to get it working (and I do have a significant lack of knowledge for Excel).

This is what I'll have:

```
------------------------------------------
itemName01    |    10/06/16    |    in    
------------------------------------------
itemName02    |    10/06/16    |    in    
------------------------------------------
itemName03    |    10/06/16    |    in    
------------------------------------------
itemName02    |    11/06/16    |    out    
------------------------------------------
itemName01    |    12/06/16    |    out    
------------------------------------------
itemName01    |    13/06/16    |    in    
------------------------------------------
itemName05    |    15/06/16    |    in    
------------------------------------------
itemName01    |    18/06/16    |    out
```

So for overtime the itemName## is added it'll start off with an "in" in col3, and then toggled.

I tried using a lookup, and then a reverse lookup to get the previous input to toggle but it kept failing with #VAL! and #REF! errors.

This is what I used for col3:

Initially, to get the value (but it returns top to bottom)

```
=LOOKUP("itemName01",A:A,B:B)
```

Then to get bottom to top

```
=IF((LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A="itemName01"),C:C )) = "in", "out", "in")
```

Comment: Assuming you have all of the items in your possession to begin with, shouldn't the initial default value be **out** and not **in** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in C2,

```
=IFERROR(IF((LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A$1=A2), C$1:C1 )) = "in", "out", "in"), "in")
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: LOOKUP_LAST]

Due to the necessity of a datetime stamp in column B you might also want to look into automation through a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro (for Excel).

Comment: scrap that, my mistake! I forgot to have the first row before the data